# Check for multiple integer values in dictionary where dictionary values are lists of integers

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this.

`{1: [1], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 2, 3], 19: [1, 2, 19], 4: [1, 2, 3, 4], 23: [1, 2, 3, 23], 20: [1, 2, 19, 20], 5: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 24: [1, 2, 3, 23, 24], 21: [1, 2, 19, 20, 21], 6: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 25: [1, 2, 3, 23, 24, 25], 22: [1, 2, 19, 20, 21, 22], 7: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 26: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26], 8: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 27: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27], 9: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 28: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27, 28], 10: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 29: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27, 28, 29], 11: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 30: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], 12: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 31: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], 13: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], 32: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32], 14: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 33: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33], 15: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 16: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], 17: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], 18: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]}`

I want to know in how many of the values, `[2,3]` are present. Similarly, I want to do it for other pairs like `[3,4]`, `[4,5]` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see how many times `[2,3]` is there:

```
sum([1 for x in d.values() if set([2, 3]).issubset(x)])
```

where `d` is your dictionary.

You can also get a list of keys that their values contain `[2,3]` (and use `len` of it):

```
[y for y,x in d.items() if set([2, 3]).issubset(x)]
```

Comment: Better: `sum({2, 3}.issubset(x) for x in d.values())`. No need to create an intermediary list.

Comment: @jpp Yes, indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum` with `all` and generator expressions. Given an input dictionary `d`:

```
L = [2, 3]
res = sum(all(i in v for i in L) for v in d.values())  # 27
```

Note this checks whether *all* the specified values exist *somewhere* within each list, i.e. irrespective of order.

#### Hashing for performance

For greater efficiency, you should `set` for dictionary values, e.g. via a one-off conversion:

```
d = {k: set(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

Once you have performed this conversion, you can use `set.issubset` for O(1) lookup complexity:

```
L = [2, 3]
L_set = {2, 3}
res = sum(L_set.issubset(v) for v in d.values())  # 27
```

Answer (score 0):

From IDLE:

```
>>> if all( x in list(range(5)) for x in [2, 3]):
    print (1)   
1
```

The `list(range(5))` simulates the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

With that, you need to iterate over every key in the dictionary, which can be accomplished as such:

```
for key in myDict:
    #Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

This checks if value of key in a dict is a superset of {2,3}:

```
for k,v in dictionary.items():
    if set(v) >= {2,3}:
        print(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.combinations` to create the pairs and find the `sum` of all lists that contains these pairs

```
>>> d = {1: [1], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 2, 3], 19: [1, 2, 19], 4: [1, 2, 3, 4], 23: [1, 2, 3, 23], 20: [1, 2, 19, 20], 5: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 24: [1, 2, 3, 23, 24], 21: [1, 2, 19, 20, 21], 6: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 25: [1, 2, 3, 23, 24, 25], 22: [1, 2, 19, 20, 21, 22], 7: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 26: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26], 8: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 27: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27], 9: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 28: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27, 28], 10: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 29: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27, 28, 29], 11: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 30: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], 12: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 31: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], 13: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], 32: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32], 14: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 33: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33], 15: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], 16: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], 17: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], 18: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]}
>>>
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> elems = set(e for l in d.values() for e in l)
>>> pairs = combinations(elems, 2)
>>> res = {pair:sum(1 for l in d.values() if all(e in l for e in pair)) for pair in pairs}
>>> {k:v for k,v in res.items() if v}
{(1, 2): 32, (1, 3): 27, (1, 4): 23, (1, 5): 22, (1, 6): 21, (1, 7): 12, (1, 8): 11, (1, 9): 10, (1, 10): 9, (1, 11): 8, (1, 12): 7, (1, 13): 6, (1, 14): 5, (1, 15): 4, (1, 16): 3, (1, 17): 2, (1, 18): 1, (1, 19): 4, (1, 20): 3, (1, 21): 2, (1, 22): 1, (1, 23): 3, (1, 24): 2, (1, 25): 1, (1, 26): 8, (1, 27): 7, (1, 28): 6, (1, 29): 5, (1, 30): 4, (1, 31): 3, (1, 32): 2, (1, 33): 1, (2, 3): 27, (2, 4): 23, (2, 5): 22, (2, 6): 21, (2, 7): 12, (2, 8): 11, (2, 9): 10, (2, 10): 9, (2, 11): 8, (2, 12): 7, (2, 13): 6, (2, 14): 5, (2, 15): 4, (2, 16): 3, (2, 17): 2, (2, 18): 1, (2, 19): 4, (2, 20): 3, (2, 21): 2, (2, 22): 1, (2, 23): 3, (2, 24): 2, (2, 25): 1, (2, 26): 8, (2, 27): 7, (2, 28): 6, (2, 29): 5, (2, 30): 4, (2, 31): 3, (2, 32): 2, (2, 33): 1, (3, 4): 23, (3, 5): 22, (3, 6): 21, (3, 7): 12, (3, 8): 11, (3, 9): 10, (3, 10): 9, (3, 11): 8, (3, 12): 7, (3, 13): 6, (3, 14): 5, (3, 15): 4, (3, 16): 3, (3, 17): 2, (3, 18): 1, (3, 23): 3, (3, 24): 2, (3, 25): 1, (3, 26): 8, (3, 27): 7, (3, 28): 6, (3, 29): 5, (3, 30): 4, (3, 31): 3, (3, 32): 2, (3, 33): 1, (4, 5): 22, (4, 6): 21, (4, 7): 12, (4, 8): 11, (4, 9): 10, (4, 10): 9, (4, 11): 8, (4, 12): 7, (4, 13): 6, (4, 14): 5, (4, 15): 4, (4, 16): 3, (4, 17): 2, (4, 18): 1, (4, 26): 8, (4, 27): 7, (4, 28): 6, (4, 29): 5, (4, 30): 4, (4, 31): 3, (4, 32): 2, (4, 33): 1, (5, 6): 21, (5, 7): 12, (5, 8): 11, (5, 9): 10, (5, 10): 9, (5, 11): 8, (5, 12): 7, (5, 13): 6, (5, 14): 5, (5, 15): 4, (5, 16): 3, (5, 17): 2, (5, 18): 1, (5, 26): 8, (5, 27): 7, (5, 28): 6, (5, 29): 5, (5, 30): 4, (5, 31): 3, (5, 32): 2, (5, 33): 1, (6, 7): 12, (6, 8): 11, (6, 9): 10, (6, 10): 9, (6, 11): 8, (6, 12): 7, (6, 13): 6, (6, 14): 5, (6, 15): 4, (6, 16): 3, (6, 17): 2, (6, 18): 1, (6, 26): 8, (6, 27): 7, (6, 28): 6, (6, 29): 5, (6, 30): 4, (6, 31): 3, (6, 32): 2, (6, 33): 1, (7, 8): 11, (7, 9): 10, (7, 10): 9, (7, 11): 8, (7, 12): 7, (7, 13): 6, (7, 14): 5, (7, 15): 4, (7, 16): 3, (7, 17): 2, (7, 18): 1, (8, 9): 10, (8, 10): 9, (8, 11): 8, (8, 12): 7, (8, 13): 6, (8, 14): 5, (8, 15): 4, (8, 16): 3, (8, 17): 2, (8, 18): 1, (9, 10): 9, (9, 11): 8, (9, 12): 7, (9, 13): 6, (9, 14): 5, (9, 15): 4, (9, 16): 3, (9, 17): 2, (9, 18): 1, (10, 11): 8, (10, 12): 7, (10, 13): 6, (10, 14): 5, (10, 15): 4, (10, 16): 3, (10, 17): 2, (10, 18): 1, (11, 12): 7, (11, 13): 6, (11, 14): 5, (11, 15): 4, (11, 16): 3, (11, 17): 2, (11, 18): 1, (12, 13): 6, (12, 14): 5, (12, 15): 4, (12, 16): 3, (12, 17): 2, (12, 18): 1, (13, 14): 5, (13, 15): 4, (13, 16): 3, (13, 17): 2, (13, 18): 1, (14, 15): 4, (14, 16): 3, (14, 17): 2, (14, 18): 1, (15, 16): 3, (15, 17): 2, (15, 18): 1, (16, 17): 2, (16, 18): 1, (17, 18): 1, (19, 20): 3, (19, 21): 2, (19, 22): 1, (20, 21): 2, (20, 22): 1, (21, 22): 1, (23, 24): 2, (23, 25): 1, (24, 25): 1, (26, 27): 7, (26, 28): 6, (26, 29): 5, (26, 30): 4, (26, 31): 3, (26, 32): 2, (26, 33): 1, (27, 28): 6, (27, 29): 5, (27, 30): 4, (27, 31): 3, (27, 32): 2, (27, 33): 1, (28, 29): 5, (28, 30): 4, (28, 31): 3, (28, 32): 2, (28, 33): 1, (29, 30): 4, (29, 31): 3, (29, 32): 2, (29, 33): 1, (30, 31): 3, (30, 32): 2, (30, 33): 1, (31, 32): 2, (31, 33): 1, (32, 33): 1}
```

Comment: I like the format of the results, but it's not accurate.
1. there are pairs like `[2,19], [3,23]` which also need to be included. Basically, all the adjacent integers form a pair.
2. There is no 0 in the dictionary values but a `[0,1]` pair in the results.
3. The results are offset by 1. e.g., `[1,2]` should have an output of 32.

Comment: Updated the answer. Check now

Comment: Sorry... Updated again. Check if check if it looks fine now

Comment: This takes all possible combination of pairs which is not needed. I need pairs of adjacent integers in the values only...
e.g. from `21: [1, 2, 19, 20, 21]`, I need pairs of `[1,2],[2,19],[19,20],[20,21]` ...

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer

Use sets and list comprehension for efficiency.

```
sample_dict= {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2: [6, 3, 7, 4, 1, 2]}
search_set = {2, 3}

count = len([i for i in sample_dict.values() if set(i) >= search_set])
```

This will generate a new list of items that match the superset criteria. The `len` of that new list is the number of matches.

#### Step by Step Explanation

1.) Iterate over the values of your dictionary:

`i for i in sample_dict.values()`

2.) Check if each item in your dictionary value list (which are themselves a list, converted to a set for a fast set intersection operation) is a superset of your search set.

`if set(i) >= search_set`

**Note**: the order of the items in the sets does not matter.

3.) Only keeping the items (the lists which were the original dictionary values) that met the criteria in step 2.

4.) Get the length of the remaining items in the list: `len()`